# How do I pass arguments in SOAP UI

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I am trying to use a SOAP api with SOAPUI. The "get" operation described in the WSDL looks like this:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:MarketingCenter" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:Get soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
             <Authentication xsi:type="urn:Authentication">
                <!--You may enter the following 6 items in any order-->
                <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">myUserName</Username>
                <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">mypassword</Password>
                <CustomerId xsi:type="xsd:int">29833</CustomerId>
                <Level xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Level>
                <Source xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Source>
                <Options xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Options>
             </Authentication>
             <Method xsi:type="xsd:string">keyword.list</Method>
             <Arguments xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfKeyValuePairs" soapenc:arrayType="urn:KeyValuePair[]"/>
          </urn:Get>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when ever I run this operation, I get the following error:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns4="urn:MarketingCenter">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns4:GetResponse>
         <return xsi:type="ns4:GetResponseData">
            <Data xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:anyType[0]" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Status>
               <ErrorCode xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ErrorCode>
               <ErrorString xsi:type="xsd:string">One or more of the arguments were invalid</ErrorString>
               <ErrorDetails xsi:type="xsd:string">One or more of the arguments were invalid</ErrorDetails>
            </Status>
         </return>
      </ns4:GetResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm not sure where I should but the list of arguments, or how to format this list.  I do realize they want an array of arguments, but where should I put this array? Wherever I was supposed to put in other values there was a '?', so I'm not sure where to input this argumentw array.

Answer (score 2):

It is expecting you to put in real values here:

```
<Authentication xsi:type="urn:Authentication">
    <!--You may enter the following 6 items in any order-->
    <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">myUserName</Username>
    <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">mypassword</Password>
    <CustomerId xsi:type="xsd:int">29833</CustomerId>
    <Level xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Level>
    <Source xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Source>
    <Options xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Options>
</Authentication>
```

The list of arguments is just `Username`, `Password`, `CustomerId`, etc.  Instead of `myUserName`, `mypassword` put in whatever the service is expecting.

As far as:

```
<Arguments xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfKeyValuePairs" soapenc:arrayType="urn:KeyValuePair[]"/>
```

That would probably look something like:

```
<urn:Get>
    ...
    <Arguments xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfKeyValuePairs" soapenc:arrayType="urn:KeyValuePair[5]">
        <KeyValuePair>
            <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">foo</Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">bar</Value>
        </KeyValuePair>
        <KeyValuePair>...</KeyValuePair>
        <KeyValuePair>...</KeyValuePair>
        <KeyValuePair>...</KeyValuePair>
        <KeyValuePair>...</KeyValuePair>
    </Arguments>
</urn:Get>
```

Where the contents of  depended on how that type is defined by the service (just a `<Key>` element and a `<Value>` element according to the WSDL).  Make sure the number in square brackets (`[5]`) matches the number of `<KeyValuePair>` elements.

Comment: Yes, I usually have those values filled in with the necessary info, but the error is speaking specifically about the arguments that are missing. I know this, because if use a method that doesn't require arguments everything works. The problem is that I don't know how to format my argument list.

Comment: Edited answer to try and address your comment.

Comment: Awesome, I think were almost there, but I specifically am having a problem with configuring the proper structure.  You can see the wsdl here: http://bit.ly/zsH8ok . please take a look and see if you can make sense of what it's looking for.